# ArcGIS server can not be used in Mobile browser and Firefox browser/ ArcGIS Javascript

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using ArcGIS JavaScript API to develop a web page to consume services from ArcGIS Server. The page loaded good in Chrome browser but not work for Firefox, and also both Android and Safari mobile browsers have issues of loading the map.

For example,

```
var pointlay = newArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/Soil_Survey_Map/MapServer",{"opacity":0.5});

map.addLayers(pointlay);
```

this code works well when using map service(layer) from ArcGIS Online, but have issues when I changed the url from my own ArcGIS Server.

Anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Please take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) if you have not done so already. Also, please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/296726/edit) your post to include the specific error messages you are seeing in each browser.

Comment: Hi Andy, there is no error messages. I tried to add layers from ArcGIS service and it shows up in Chrome browser. However, when I open the same page in Firefox and moblie browser(IOS and Andriod) the added layers disappear. I then tried to add layers from ArcGIS online and the page worked well in all browsers. So I think there could be something wrong with my published map services.

Comment: Hi Joe, welcome. As Andy said could you elaborate on the issue? 
For example: 
which version of JS are you using? 
are the browsers up to date? 
What are the capabilities you provide with your map service on ArcGIS Server? Have you tested without opacity? etc etc etc

Comment: Hi Joe. Your web page is in http or https? Your ArcGIS Server service is in http or https? Firefox with mixed content is very hard...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without more details, but you may be facing a CORS issue. Please see [this documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/ags_proxy.html) and use the [Resource Proxy](https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy) or enable CORS on your server.